# function_name is not defined error

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I want to write a function in python that tells if the number I give is prime, my code so far is:

```
def enter_input():
    n=input("Enter the number to be checked\n")
    return n

def check():
    o=int(enter_input())
    r=o
    print(type(o))
    print(type(r))
    bool=True
    for i in range(2,r,1):
        if(o%i==0):
            return False
    return True

def display():
    print("Entered Number Is {0}".format(p))
    print("The Number is a Prime:{0}".format(check()))


enter_input()
check()
display()
```

---

But I get this error after input the numer:

RunTime:-

```
Enter the number to be checked
23
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Chech_Prime.py", line 8, in check
    o=int(enter_input())
    NameError: name 'enter_input' is not defined
```

***Repl Closed***

Where did I go wrong? This was my first try with function calling, It seems like the place i called the enter_input() function could not find it. Thanks for any help

Comment: Where is "p" variable defined?

Comment: I'm sorry about the 'p' , it should have been 'o'. However the problem still persists.

Comment: Okey, I modified a liitle bit your code try it, in the mid time i will write an explain to you

Comment: Let me know if that works for you, I will update soon with a comparation with your code telling you where did you made little mistakes, and why I did what I did

Comment: I added to you the explain of why your code didn't work, and why I did mine. Good bye!

Comment: Yes I understood the problem Damian , My entire code was pretty much gibberish and I realized that I called the enter_input function too many times. Thanks for the explanation and the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write somethings a little odd, so I will explain why this should do what you are specting:

This is your code, I will comment between lines:

```
def enter_input():
    n=input("Enter the number to be checked\n")
    return n 

def check(): # you create the check function, and then a display function, and is not necesary, because you want to do both thinks in the same function
    o=int(enter_input()) # you call this function a lot of times, and you only want to input the value once, so, is better to call the input method inside the function
    r=o # is better to name variables more descriptive, I mean, check() as a function, what checks? maybe you want to call it is_prime(), more descriptive, o and p... doesn't say anything, but input sounds better
    print(type(o))
    print(type(r)) #this auxiliar variable is not needed
    bool=True
    for i in range(2,r,1):
        if(o%i==0):
            return False
    return True

def display():
    print("Entered Number Is {0}".format(p))
    print("The Number is a Prime:{0}".format(check()))# here you again call the function, and again it ask to you to add a input... not good


enter_input()
check() # and again.. three times, that's so confusing even to follow when you are adding the inputs
display()
```

My way to do it will be:

```
def print_is_prime():
    value_to_eval=int(input("Enter the number to be checked\n"))

    print("the type of the value is " + str(value_to_eval.__class__.__name__))

    is_prime =True #initial value is correct
    for i in range(2,value_to_eval,1):
        if(value_to_eval%i==0):
            is_prime = False #here, you detect is not prime
            break # so with break you can avoid to execute innecesary all the loop

    is_prime = True and is_prime # with and operator, true is the neutral, so the value will be always the other value, in this case, is_prime, this like 0 + x, the value will be always x

    print("Entered Number Is {0}".format(value_to_eval))
    print("The Number is a Prime:{0}".format(is_prime))

print_is_prime()
```

Comment: Thanks Damian , the modiifed code worked. I was trying to learn functions and the way they call each other so i made 3 different functions instead of one. I'll go through the new code and sort out the problem.

Comment: @Ritesh_BM I have always love to help, don't forget accepting with the (✓) and voting if you liked :)